# Coerce built-ins to their GL equivalents

Tags: opengl, haskell, types, casting, functional-programming

I just wrote a quick Conway's Game of Life in Haskell for practice and I though that I should now animate it.

I wanted to use GLUT + OpenGL and few seconds of Googling later, I had an example up and ready to fire. The difference in the example is that it defines a function that returns some points as `myPoints :: [(GLfloat,GLfloat,GLfloat)]` whereas I have `Coord` defined as `data Coord = Coord {x :: Int, y :: Int} deriving (Show, Eq)`. That's all nice and neat and the game seems to work in its plain form, but there are issues when I try to draw it. Namely the part when I am supposed to pass the points to the renderer:
`renderPrimitive Points $ mapM_ (\(x, y, z)->vertex$Vertex3 x y z) myPoints`
That's all fine if `myPoints` contains values of type `GLfloat` but `renderPrimitive Points $ mapM_ (\(Coord x y)->vertex$Vertex2 x y) myCoords` complains:

```
No instance for (VertexComponent Int)
  arising from a use of `vertex'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (VertexComponent Int)
```

I tried things like `fromIntegral x` and adding a type signatures `:: GLfloat` or `GLint` but it always seems to complain that it can't take the type or that it can't go Int -> GLfloat/GLint.

My question is, how do I get my Coord type to play with OpenGL types? I can't find any hint on the Web and I'd rather not make `Coord = Coord {x :: GLfloat, y :: GLfloat}` for the simple reason that the whole lot of other code will not play nicely with GLfloats as it's all expecting `Num` or `Int` and whatnot.

Below is minimum scenario where the issue is illustrated and which I'd love to be able to compile:

```
module Main
where

import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

data Coord = Coord {x :: Int, y :: Int} deriving (Show, Eq)

someCoords = [Coord 1 1, Coord 1 2, Coord 42 7]

main = do
  (progName, _) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  createWindow "Please compile."
  displayCallback $= display
  mainLoop

display = do
  clear [ColorBuffer]
  renderPrimitive Points $ mapM_ (\(Coord x y) -> vertex $ Vertex2 x y) someCoords
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hunting for a longer while with another programmer in my household, we have found a snippet of code which let us make GLfloat from an int, namely `fromIntegral x :: GLfloat` will produce the desired result. Similarly, `fromRational` can be used for `Float -> GLfloat`.

Comment: `fromIntegral` is useful for conversions between integral types like `Int`, `Integer`, `Word` etc. `realToFrac` is probably the most optimized function for converting between `Float`, `Double`, `GLfloat` etc.